# A learned scholar and the pronunciation of learned

Tags: meaning, word-usage, pronunciation

[Source:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/learned) Cambridge Dictionary

> **learned**
>
> adjective fml US ​  /ˈlɜr·nɪd/
>
> having or showing much knowledge:
>
> *a learned scholar*

I was checking the word ***learned*** and the example sentence made me wonder if there is ***unlearned scholar/professor***?

In addition to that, there are three pronunciations of the word **learned**. /lɜːnd/ /lɜːnt/ /ˈlɜː.nɪd/

I have always heard /lɜːnd/. When I use software to read the paragraph, interestingly it pronounces ***learned*** differently depends on the sentence structure. How do I know when to pronounce as /lɜːnd/ and when to pronounce as /ˈlɜː.nɪd/?

Comment: Isn't the pronunciation ending in "t" for the word "learnt" rather than "learned"?

Comment: If the context is the same as where learnt would also apply (past tense of learn; acquired by study or experience) use the one-syllable pronunciation, and in other cases (having knowledge, scholarly, well-informed) use the two-syllable pronunciation.

Comment: The pronunciation was discussed in a previous question where it seems that the third way is a British usage when the context of "a learned scholar" is similar to "a wise man". In other words when "learned" is an adjective, for example "my learned friend."

Comment: **I was checking the word learned and the example sentence made me wonder if there is unlearned scholar/professor?**

I am sure there are many who consider some professors as such. However by default I would suggest that word cannot exist unless qualifications are handed out without the students having been educated.

Comment: "unlearned scholar" seems to be an oxymoron, I don't think it's a thing.